# Is it possible to automatically convert a Union type to only one type automatically with pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic

Given the following data model:

```py
class Demo(BaseModel):
  id: Union[int, str]
  files: Union[str, List[str]]
```

Is there a way to tell `pydantic` to always convert `id` to `str` type and `files` to `List[str]` type automatically when I access them, instead of doing this manually every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pydantic has built-in validation logic built-in for most of the common types out there. This includes `str`. It just so happens that the default string validator simply coerces values of type `int`, `float` or `Decimal` to `str` by default. (see [`str_validator` source](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.4/pydantic/validators.py#L65))

This means even if you annotate `id` as `str`, but pass an `int` value, the model will initialize properly without validation error and the `id` value will be the `str` version of that value. (e.g. `str(42)` gives `"42"`)

`list` also has a default validator built-in, but in this case it may be not what you want. If it encounters a non-`list` value, but sees that it is a sequence (or a generator), it again coerces it to a `list`. (see [`list_validator` source](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.4/pydantic/validators.py#L264)) In this case, since the value you might pass to it will be a `str` and a `str` is a sequence, the outcome would be a list of single-character strings from the initial string. (e.g. `list("abc")` gives `["a", "b", "c"]`)

So for `list[str]` you will likely need your own custom `pre=True` [validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) to perform whatever you deem necessary with the `str` value to turn it into a `list[str]`.

Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Demo(BaseModel):
    id: str
    files: list[str]

    @validator("files", pre=True)
    def str_to_list_of_str(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return v.split(",")
        return v


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Demo.parse_obj({"id": 42, "files": "foo,bar,baz"})
    print(obj)
    print(type(obj.id), type(obj.files))
```

Output:

```
id='42' files=['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
<class 'str'> <class 'list'>
```

As you can see, you don't even need any additional `id` field logic, if your values are `int` because they end up as `str` on the model instance.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to make it after get help from the maintainer. The key point is to remove `Union` from the type definition and use a pre-process hook to convert the value before validation, here is the sample code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from typing import List

class Demo(BaseModel):
    id: str
    files: List[str]

    @validator('id', pre=True)
    def id_must_be_str(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, int):
            v = str(v)
        return v

    @validator('files', pre=True)
    def files_must_be_list_of_str(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, str):
            v = [v]
        return v


obj = Demo.parse_obj({'id': 1, 'files': '/data/1.txt'})

print(type(obj.id))
print(type(obj.files))
```